# FB Messenger Bot: messaging_events.length --> cannot read property length

Tags: node.js, heroku, facebook-messenger-bot

Good day, I am having a problem with my bot, namely, that my webhook has not been responding on time to facebook - I get the following message from the developers page:

> Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://istoryabot.herokuapp.com/webhook has not been accepting updates for at least 10 minutes. Please verify that your callback server is functioning. Visit our reference documentation to learn how to update your callback URL.
>
> If your callback URL is still failing after 50 minutes your subscription will be disabled. To reactivate, just make a POST request with the same parameters or visit the Webhooks tab in the app dashboard.

As such, the bot has been disabled. My bot is hosted on heroku, and I get this result when I go to the webhook page:

[Forbidden] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebzyl4tb49jv5y4/Screenshot%20%28757%29.png?dl=0)

However, as an admin of the page and of the bot app, I am still able to see and test out the bot's functionality even if in developer mode. I have verified that the bot returns the proper responses over messenger, but still, the webhook url is failing. Can anyone help me out? My code and logs will be found below.

CODE:

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var rp = require("request-promise");

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var stringSearcher = require("string-search");
var async = require("async");
var crypto = require('crypto');

var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));

const Rules = require('./script.json');

// App Secret can be retrieved from the App Dashboard
const APP_SECRET = process.env.APP_SECRET ;

// Arbitrary value used to validate a webhook
const VERIFICATION_TOKEN = process.env.VERIFICATION;

// Generate a page access token for your page from the App Dashboard
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;

// Server index page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Deployed!");
});

// Facebook Webhook
// Used for verification
app.get("/webhook/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.query["hub.verify_token"] === APP_SECRET) {
        console.log("Verified webhook");
        res.status(200).send(req.query["hub.challenge"]);
    } else {
        console.error("Verification failed. The tokens do not match.");
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }
});

app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    //var rn = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    //var rn_string = rn.toString();
    //console.log("@APP POST, GENERATED RANDOM NUMBER: "+rn_string);
    console.log("@APP POST");
    
    var data = req.body;
    
    if (data.object === 'page') {

        // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batcheds
        data.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

            // Get the webhook event. entry.messaging is an array, but 
            // will only ever contain one event, so we get index 0
            let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
            console.log("WEBHOOK RECEIVED");
            console.log(webhook_event);
          
            let sender = webhook_event.sender.id
            
            
            if(webhook_event.postback){
                let payload = webhook_event.postback.payload
                
                console.log("POSTBACK DETECTED!");
                console.log("PAYLOAD: "+payload);
                if(payload == "Greeting") {
                    processPostback2(webhook_event);
                } else {
                    processPostback(webhook_event, '');
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("NOT A POSTBACK");
            }
          
        });

        // Return a '200 OK' response to all events
        res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');

    } else {
        // Return a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
    
});
function getUserProfile(event) {
    console.log("@USERPROFILE");
    
    var senderId = event.sender.id;
    var first_name = 'INITIAL';

    const user_profile_options = {  
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+senderId+'?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token='+PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
    };
    return rp(user_profile_options);
}

function processPostback2(event) {
    console.log("@PROCESSPOSTBACK2");
    getUserProfile(event).then(response => {
        console.log("DATA TYPE OF RESPONSE: "+typeof(response));
        console.log("CONTENT OF RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(response));
        var first_name = response.first_name;
        processPostback(event, first_name);
        resolve(1);
    }).catch(err => {
        // you have some error
    });
}

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
    let messageData = { text:text }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {id:sender},
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
        }
    })
}

function processPostback(event, first_name) {
    console.log("@PROCESSPOSTBACK");
    //first_name = userProfile(event);
    
    console.log("ENTERED PROCESS POSTBACK PROCESS WITH THIS FIRSTNAME: "+first_name);
    
    var senderId = event.sender.id;
    var payload = event.postback.payload;
    
    if (Rules.hasOwnProperty(payload.toUpperCase())) {
        sendSingleJsonMessage(senderId,Rules[payload.toUpperCase()], first_name);
    }
}

// sends message to user
function sendMessage(recipientId, message) {
  request({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/167446456648112/messages",
    qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
    method: "POST",
    json: {
      recipient: {id: recipientId},
      message: message,
    }
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error sending message: " + response.error);
    }
  });
}

//send single JSON message
function sendSingleJsonMessage(recipientId,filename, first_name) {
    console.log("@SENDSINGLEJSONMESSAGE");
    try {
      filename = "./script/" + filename;
      var json  = require(filename);
      var fullMessage = { recipient: { id: recipientId  }};
      var body = JSON.stringify(json);
      
      console.log("ORIGINAL BODY: "+body);
      console.log("SEND SINGLE JSON MESSAGE "+first_name);
 
      const promise = stringSearcher.find(body, '<first_name>')
      .then(function(resultArr) {
            console.log("replace first_name with "+first_name);
            if (body.search("<first_name>") != -1) {
                    console.log("FOUND");
                    body = body.replace("<first_name>", first_name);
            } else {
                    console.log("NOT FOUND");
            }
            console.log("NEW BODY: "+body);
      });
      
      const promise2 = promise.then (function (result){
          fullMessage.message = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(fullMessage));
      });
      
      const promise3 = promise2.then(function (result2){
          sendFullAPI(fullMessage);
      });
   }
   catch (e)
   {
      message = "catch section ";
      sendMessage(recipientId, {text: message});
      console.log("error in sendSingleJsonMessage " + e.message + " " + filename + " " + fullMessage);
   }
}

// sends card to user
function sendFullAPI(message) {
    console.log("@SENDFULLAPI");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    request({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
        qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
        method: "POST",
        json: message,
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Error sending message: " + response.error);
        }
    });
}
```

LOG:

```
2018-08-08T08:29:29.027786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=32f7c71f-309b-4816-ae27-bd2199966acd fwd="69.171.240.83" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025741+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025778+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025912+00:00 app[web.1]: { recipient: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025914+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533716968745,
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025915+00:00 app[web.1]:   sender: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025917+00:00 app[web.1]:   postback: { payload: 'Greeting', title: 'Get Started' } }
2018-08-08T08:29:29.025958+00:00 app[web.1]: POSTBACK DETECTED!
2018-08-08T08:29:29.026014+00:00 app[web.1]: PAYLOAD: Greeting
2018-08-08T08:29:29.026075+00:00 app[web.1]: @PROCESSPOSTBACK2
2018-08-08T08:29:29.026128+00:00 app[web.1]: @USERPROFILE
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103406+00:00 app[web.1]: DATA TYPE OF RESPONSE: object
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103476+00:00 app[web.1]: CONTENT OF RESPONSE: {"first_name":"Aldon","last_name":"Galido","profile_pic":"https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?psid=2434229289927905&width=1024&ext=1536308969&hash=AeQ_wx1iW_uBVIx6","id":"2434229289927905"}
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103529+00:00 app[web.1]: @PROCESSPOSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103580+00:00 app[web.1]: ENTERED PROCESS POSTBACK PROCESS WITH THIS FIRSTNAME: Aldon
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103650+00:00 app[web.1]: @SENDSINGLEJSONMESSAGE
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103771+00:00 app[web.1]: ORIGINAL BODY: {"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"button","text":"Hello <first_name>!\n\nHow can we help you?","buttons":[{"type":"postback","title":"General Inquiry","payload":"GENERAL INQUIRY"},{"type":"postback","title":"Custom Message","payload":"CUSTOM MESSAGE"}]}}}
2018-08-08T08:29:29.103823+00:00 app[web.1]: SEND SINGLE JSON MESSAGE Aldon
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104435+00:00 app[web.1]: replace first_name with Aldon
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104498+00:00 app[web.1]: FOUND
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104566+00:00 app[web.1]: NEW BODY: {"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"button","text":"Hello Aldon!\n\nHow can we help you?","buttons":[{"type":"postback","title":"General Inquiry","payload":"GENERAL INQUIRY"},{"type":"postback","title":"Custom Message","payload":"CUSTOM MESSAGE"}]}}}
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104676+00:00 app[web.1]: {"recipient":{"id":"2434229289927905"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"button","text":"Hello Aldon!\n\nHow can we help you?","buttons":[{"type":"postback","title":"General Inquiry","payload":"GENERAL INQUIRY"},{"type":"postback","title":"Custom Message","payload":"CUSTOM MESSAGE"}]}}}}
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104738+00:00 app[web.1]: @SENDFULLAPI
2018-08-08T08:29:29.104803+00:00 app[web.1]: {"recipient":{"id":"2434229289927905"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"button","text":"Hello Aldon!\n\nHow can we help you?","buttons":[{"type":"postback","title":"General Inquiry","payload":"GENERAL INQUIRY"},{"type":"postback","title":"Custom Message","payload":"CUSTOM MESSAGE"}]}}}}
2018-08-08T08:29:29.264501+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265125+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265128+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:60:39
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265130+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265132+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:56:14
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265136+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265139+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265141+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265145+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265146+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265148+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265149+00:00 app[web.1]:     at urlencodedParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265151+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265152+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265154+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265156+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265159+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265160+00:00 app[web.1]:     at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265167+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265168+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.265169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.266257+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=2f2bc8ca-a0fb-4a8f-aaf8-a5130f41cf0e fwd="173.252.85.199" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:29.509418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=d4953a8c-5ed4-47ca-8f39-0449af107cee fwd="173.252.84.115" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:29.507548+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510342+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510344+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:60:39
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:56:14
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510349+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510352+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510353+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510354+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510356+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510357+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510358+00:00 app[web.1]:     at urlencodedParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510359+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510360+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510361+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510362+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510363+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510365+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510366+00:00 app[web.1]:     at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510367+00:00 app[web.1]:     at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510368+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510369+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510370+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510371+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510372+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.510373+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.752490+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753085+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:60:39
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753090+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:56:14
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753092+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753093+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753097+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753098+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753100+00:00 app[web.1]:     at urlencodedParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753101+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753103+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753104+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753106+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753107+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753108+00:00 app[web.1]:     at invokeCallback (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at done (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753111+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753112+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753113+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753114+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753115+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753116+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2018-08-08T08:29:29.753422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=8c837396-d1d9-4c4f-a5a0-0b44d0175a65 fwd="173.252.84.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187104+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187170+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187437+00:00 app[web.1]: { sender: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187439+00:00 app[web.1]:   recipient: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187441+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533716969732,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187443+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187444+00:00 app[web.1]:    { is_echo: true,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187446+00:00 app[web.1]:      app_id: 400867433721637,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187454+00:00 app[web.1]:      mid: 'Mxpu1fCA5OB_R1eOhi_jtRsjxze7cyi3viFlvr2evRk99WHkP7p6u5_13sBtT4Zfp1Kyqf0Hy6PS3KKWxePKEw',
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187456+00:00 app[web.1]:      seq: 3012628,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187458+00:00 app[web.1]:      text: 'Hello Aldon!\n\nHow can we help you?',
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187459+00:00 app[web.1]:      attachments: [ [Object] ] } }
2018-08-08T08:29:31.187507+00:00 app[web.1]: NOT A POSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:29:31.415870+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:31.415885+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416043+00:00 app[web.1]: { sender: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416045+00:00 app[web.1]:   recipient: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416047+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533716970492,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416049+00:00 app[web.1]:   delivery: 
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416051+00:00 app[web.1]:    { mids: 
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416053+00:00 app[web.1]:       [ 'Mxpu1fCA5OB_R1eOhi_jtRsjxze7cyi3viFlvr2evRk99WHkP7p6u5_13sBtT4Zfp1Kyqf0Hy6PS3KKWxePKEw' ],
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416055+00:00 app[web.1]:      watermark: 1533716969732,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416056+00:00 app[web.1]:      seq: 0 } }
2018-08-08T08:29:31.416077+00:00 app[web.1]: NOT A POSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:29:31.188389+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=2e36a22c-b95c-497c-b135-bc14fdd44362 fwd="45.64.41.8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:31.417388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=8873871c-94c2-4ebb-b0f3-8f9d24fddacf fwd="45.64.41.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570000+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570181+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570338+00:00 app[web.1]: { sender: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570341+00:00 app[web.1]:   recipient: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570363+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533716970699,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570365+00:00 app[web.1]:   delivery: 
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570367+00:00 app[web.1]:    { mids: 
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570369+00:00 app[web.1]:       [ 'Mxpu1fCA5OB_R1eOhi_jtRsjxze7cyi3viFlvr2evRk99WHkP7p6u5_13sBtT4Zfp1Kyqf0Hy6PS3KKWxePKEw' ],
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570371+00:00 app[web.1]:      watermark: 1533716969732,
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570373+00:00 app[web.1]:      seq: 0 } }
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570401+00:00 app[web.1]: NOT A POSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:29:31.570963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=feac2305-cec0-40dd-8ab2-7951951e4d05 fwd="45.64.41.8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:30:52.087932+00:00 app[web.1]: @APP POST
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088066+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088380+00:00 app[web.1]: { sender: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088383+00:00 app[web.1]:   recipient: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088385+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533717051208,
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088387+00:00 app[web.1]:   read: { watermark: 1533716969732, seq: 0 } }
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088491+00:00 app[web.1]: NOT A POSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:30:52.089403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=df114f8a-7e8f-472e-9dea-a3631a4b6585 fwd="45.64.40.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:31:09.525673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=64e7434d-45f8-4bf5-bc47-6dd6607baad6 fwd="202.92.130.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=215 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:31:09.528449+00:00 app[web.1]: Verification failed. The tokens do not match.
2018-08-08T08:31:49.642921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=d2b1432e-e3da-4985-a87d-b73deb973c0a fwd="202.92.130.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=207 protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088066+00:00 app[web.1]: WEBHOOK RECEIVED
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088380+00:00 app[web.1]: { sender: { id: '2434229289927905' },
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088385+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1533717051208,
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088383+00:00 app[web.1]:   recipient: { id: '167446456648112' },
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088387+00:00 app[web.1]:   read: { watermark: 1533716969732, seq: 0 } }
2018-08-08T08:30:52.088491+00:00 app[web.1]: NOT A POSTBACK
2018-08-08T08:30:52.089403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=df114f8a-7e8f-472e-9dea-a3631a4b6585 fwd="45.64.40.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=213 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:31:09.525673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/webhook" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=64e7434d-45f8-4bf5-bc47-6dd6607baad6 fwd="202.92.130.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=215 protocol=https
2018-08-08T08:31:09.528449+00:00 app[web.1]: Verification failed. The tokens do not match.
2018-08-08T08:31:49.642921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=istoryabot.herokuapp.com request_id=d2b1432e-e3da-4985-a87d-b73deb973c0a fwd="202.92.130.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=207 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure  "data.entry" is an array then only "forEach" will work.

Comment: I'm basing my code on FB's quick start tutorial found here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start